# Exception in Nginx sub_filter

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I want to use the Nginx `sub_filter` module and I want to except some files to substitute. Is there a good and clean solution for that?
For example, I want to replace `str_1` to `str_2` in all javascripts, but not those that have some property like location, name, or even size.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you use `sub_filter_types` it is added on top `text/html`, so pay attention for that. (So `text/html` is always replaced)

This is why you should use the `sub_filter` directive in different contexts of `location` block.

I do not know a way to instruct Nginx to `sub_filter` based on file size.

Remember that Nginx will replace the string in the current buffer, flush this buffer, and continue to the next buffer.